# How do I get the Resource object from URI in django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Say I have some ModelResource classes and they are registered with a tastypie API endpoint (say api/v1/posts, api/v1/authors).

Given a URI (such a api/v1/posts), I need to get an instance of PostResource so as to execute PostResource.get_list()

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):
    def get_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
class AuthorResource(ModelResource):
    def get_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

**Question is** - Given the url `api/v1/posts`, what is the pythonic/django/tastypie way to get an instance of PostResource?

I can anyways maintain a reverse mapping in my code and that would work, but there would definitely be a better solution.

Comment: You don't need to override `get_list`. Have you set the `ForeignkeyField` on the resource?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `get_via_uri` function.

You probably need this part:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, get_script_prefix, Resolver404
from tastypie.exceptions import NotFound

prefix = get_script_prefix()
chomped_uri = uri

if prefix and chomped_uri.startswith(prefix):
    chomped_uri = chomped_uri[len(prefix)-1:]

try:
    resource, args, kwargs = resolve(chomped_uri)
except Resolver404:
    raise NotFound("The URL provided '%s' was not a link to a valid resource." % uri)
```

Where `uri` is Your `URI`. `resource` is Your Resource instance.